# Using \@ifstar to define a star variant

Tags: macros, starred-version

Why does the following not work at all?

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\@ifstar{\textbf{#1}}{\textit{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{test}
\foo*{test}

\end{document}
```

The output seems to be "test" written correctly as italicized for the non-star variant and "*test" ("test" written normally with no bold weight, "*" written italicized) written for the star variant.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The reason is that with `\foo*{test}` `*` is the argument for `\foo` and `{test}` is just the word text in a group. `\foo` must be a macro without argument, which calls another macro with argument

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar{\@foob}{\@fooi}}
\newcommand{\@foob}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\@fooi}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{test}
\foo*{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course, the definition of `\foo` could be simplified as in the other answers. But this answer is valuable because it covers the general case, if the code arguments of `\@ifstar` are more complex than a simple `\textbf` or `\textit`.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because the original issue I had was with redefining `\section`, and I came up with `\textbf` vs `\textit` as a better minimal example, which coincidentally had a better solution not applicable to my problem.

Answer (score 18):

Macro `\foo` is defined with one argument. If it is called as `\foo*{test}`, then the star becomes the argument (`#1`); *then* `\foo` is expanded and `\@ifstar` is called. But the following token `{` is not a star. The argument, the star, is then set as `\textit{*}`. The processing of `\foo` is finished and `{test}` is interpreted as group with the word `test` inside.

The example can be fixed the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\foo}{\@ifstar\textbf\textit}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{test}
\foo*{test}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Macro `\foo` is defined without argument, thus that `\@ifstar` can look for a following star. Then the code in the arguments for "with star" and "without star" of `\@ifstar` read the following argument.

If the code in the argument of `\@ifstar` is more complicate, then the more general [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376380/16967) of Mike helps.

Answer (score 11):

In your definition the argument has already been read before the \@ifstar comes into the picture. So you would have to  put the star behind the argument (remaek that it eats a space::

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{\@ifstar{\textbf{#1}}{\textit{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{test}
\foo{test}*

\end{document}
```

[image]

But what you want is probably this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar\textbf\textit}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{test}
\foo*{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As you have it, with `\foo*` the `*` is already consumed as `#1`, use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar{\textbf}{\textit}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\foo{test}
\foo*{test}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

With `xparse` it would be:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\foo{sm}{\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\textbf{#2}}{\textit{#2}}}
```